# Google Map Geo Coding Pricing

Tags: google-maps

I apologize if this has been discussed before.  I could not find it.

The company I work for just inherited a web application that heavily uses Google maps.  Once a month it has to geo code thousands of properties and save the longitude and latitude in the database.  Then Google map is used when these properties are viewed on the website.

I know that Google will start charging for their services soon.  Are they going to charge for just map views? Or are going to charge for geo coding  as well? What is going to happen when we go over the limit?  Are they going to shut our service down for the day or forever?

Do they keep count based on IP of the requesting server?

I am trying to lean about Google Maps as fast as I can.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google will only start charging for use of the otherwise Free API if over a 90 day period the site gets more than 25000 map views a day. It's worth noting that should only impact about .35% of sites, that's right under one half of one percent. Usage will be tracked by Developer Keys, which you can obtain through the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). The limits for server-side geocoding are 2500 a day, that's regardless of whether you fall under the new usage limits. Check out the [Google Geo Developers Blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/11/understanding-how-maps-api-usage-limits.html) for more information on the new usage limits. If more geocoding quota is needed, or if the company wants to display data on limited-access websites, that is not freely available, or uses the maps for asset tracking. then they should obtain an [Enterprise license](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html).